# Remove index from output

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting a certain value from a column based on the row i am matching from.
I am appending the value into a list, but it gives me the index from where the value is extracted from. Here is the code:

```
for i in range (len(lstr.iloc[9])):
    if i == 0:
        interest_CM = list()
    interest = df_key.loc[df_key['Colum_name1'] == lstr[9][i]] 
    interest_CM.append(interest['Column_name2'].to_string())
```

explanation of code: Column_name1 is where im finding the string that matches to the specific string in lstr[9]. Example first element string is 'apple', hence find the row that has 'apple' in Column_name1 of df_key. Then append the string in interest['Column_name2'] into interest_CM. 2nd element string is pear.

The output i got was:
['5511    apple', '5407    pear']

I do not want the index 5511 and 5407 appended into list. How do I code this

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can pass `index=False` as a *kwarg* to [`pandas.Series.to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_string.html) :

```
interest_CM = []

for i in range (len(lstr.iloc[9])):
    interest = df_key.loc[df_key['Colum_name1'] == lstr[9][i]] 
    interest_CM.append(interest['Column_name2'].to_string(index=False))
```